# Android - Seekbar custom progress scaling

Tags: android, progress-bar, custom-controls, seekbar

I'm trying to modify my seekbar behavior to make it more similar to iOS systems where, as far as you are from seekbar rect in y-coordinates, it will slow down your seek-progress. And when you are returning to your seekbar, it will update your progress scaling to where you are as such, when you touch the seekbar, you have a ratio of 1/1 over x-swipe / progressbar of seekbar.

I would like to achieve something like this: when you are say 50 pixels over seekbar ( in y direction), my scaling factor should be say 3/1: when you are moving 3 pixels away in x-direction, your seekbar should move 1 pixel, accordingly to your x-axis sign, obviously. In summa, something like ipod music tracking seekbar, or video player (I think MX player for Android has something like what I'm looking for).

Is there a way to do that?

What I tried is overriding seekbar.setOnTouchListener, but from here I have no idea about what I can do for simulate such a thing. I think is something related to seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener ... How can I override the "link" between gesture detection and calculation of progress bar, the same progress bar that I can find inside my setOnSeekBarChangeListener.OnProgressChanged method? Is there some method like seekbar.setScalingProgressFactor for imposing ration of 3/1 pixels along x axis, in dependence of y coordinates?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OnTouch of your activity, use:

```
int x = event.getX(), y = event.getY();
```

Then, check to see how far the y coordinate is by using:

```
int distance = mySeekbarY - y;
if (distance == 0) {
    double ScalingFactor = 1;
else {
    double ScalingFactor = 50/(3*Math.abs(distance));
}
```

When the click is 50px away, distance becomes 50. Plugging 50 into the formula, we get 50/(3*50) = 1/3 as you require. We needed the if-else statement to handle the case when distance is 0. Plugging 0 into the formula would get you 50/0 which would give you an error. Now do:

```
double toMove = (x-mySeekbarX)*ScalingFactor;
```

And then add toMove to the X coordinate of your seekbar. :D

Hope I helped :D

Comment: yeah thank you so much! But what did you mean saying "x coordinate of seekbar"? You suggest to use "seekbar.setProgress(toMove)", did you? Sorry for silly question ... :)

Comment: @pippo Not quite, get a variable that keeps track of the current progress of seekbar. Then, add toMove to it and then set that as the Progress. If you need help, do ask! P.s. If you think the answer is satisfactory, mark it as accepted and maybe vote it up? ;D

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness! You helped me a lot in my work! So I found this solution: as you suggested, I overrided the setOnTouchListener and kept track of my position when clicked on the seekbar view. The scalingfactor stuff is like what you wrote, but I inserted a little trick to do it more smoothy: I divided my event.getX() for (seekbar.getWidth() / seekbar.getMax() ) in order to make my x-axis movement more similar to my seekbar movements ;) and then setProgress(getProgress() + toMove), all inside my seekbar onTouchListener. All goes right now! thanks so much!! :)